# Semicolon error and wrong parametric plot

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot [green, domain=-0.25:2.5,line width=1pt,-latex,smooth] (-4/exp(x), 2*(4*x - 1)*exp(-x));
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the produced output:

[image]

This is the output of Mathematica:

[image]

What is happening here?

I do not understand and can only speculate that there is an unnatural order of operations inside the system.

Comment: Mathematically, they are the same, no?

Comment: I'm confused, why are you asking me this? 1/exp(x) = exp(-x), so I don't see where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My fault. In Mathematica code it is multiplication, but in your code you used a division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only forgot braces, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle]
\addplot [green, domain=-0.25:2.5,line width=1pt,-latex,smooth] ({-4/exp(x)},
{2*(4*x - 1)*exp(-x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can add some options to make the scaling of the axes equal.